# VFP 9.0 writing the status window out to a file

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

Is it possible to write out the status window in VisualFoxPro 9?  Not talking about the command window, but the base window of the program that generates text when you use:

```
? "SomeTextHere"
```

[image]

I want to be able to write out all the text to a txt file.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to capture what's already there as text. (You can, of course, use a utility like SnagIt to capture an image.)

To capture the output as it's generated, try SET PRINT.

Tamar